# how to write method which returns object?

Tags: c#

Is this a write way?suggest me.

```
public Init_Circle Init_Circle(Point pt,double rad)
{
    Point center=pt;

    if (rbCircle.Checked==true)
    {
        pt.x = double.Parse(txtCirCntPtX.Text.Trim());
        pt.y = double.Parse(txtCirCntPtY.Text.Trim());
        rad = double.Parse(txtCirRadius.Text.Trim());

    }
    return this.Init_Circle(pt,rad);
}
```

Comment: You are not supposed to return anything from constructor.

Comment: Your code event won't compile if you want to specify return type in a constructor.

Comment: Without the bigger picture this just looks like an infinite recursive loop, which will eventually give you a stack overflow. What are you trying to do? Maybe you meant to write (or invoke) a constructor at some point?

Answer (score 1):

You can't return anything from the constructor, but what you can do is create a static method that creates the object for you.

So in your constructor do it like this.

```
private Init_Circle()
{

}
```

and create a method like this

```
public static Init_Circle CreateInstance(// parameters here)
{
    // do object creation here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a method which will returns object. You can't return anything in a constructor.

Method should look like this:

```
public Init_Circle ReturnCircle(Point pt,double rad)
{
    Point center=pt;
    if (rbCircle.Checked==true)
    {
        pt.x = double.Parse(txtCirCntPtX.Text.Trim());
        pt.y = double.Parse(txtCirCntPtY.Text.Trim());
        rad = double.Parse(txtCirRadius.Text.Trim());
     }
    return this.Init_Circle(pt,rad);
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is the right code. Assuming **Init_Circle** is a class name, he can't return this way.

Comment: @RohitPrakash C# allow create method with name equals class name

Comment: @Grundy, right. But the way he has written his code, doesn't look like he was trying to write a method.

Comment: @RohitPrakash I edit answer for You.

Comment: @RohitPrakash why not? we don't see all code, so we can only guess what OP do :-)